# Correct Connection string for accessing remote database server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have developed a c# program I want to use to access a remote server from a client computer on the same domain.Every time I try to connect to the database I am getting an error login failed for user domain\myclientusername

Using the connection string below:

```
 <add name="dbname" connectionString="Server=remoteservername;Database=dbname;Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

I have already checked and the server is set to allow remote connections. I am able to log on to the server using admin credentials do I need to set the connection string to use admin password and user name to connect to the database? or do I need to add my client profile credentials  to the database permissions. Very new to deploying applications.

Comment: Using integrated security = true, means they use the same username and password to login to the database as they do to log into the computer. Is this true for everyone, or just you?

Comment: Is your application a desktop (WPF/Forms), or is it an intranet/IIS application?

Comment: Instead of `Integrated Security=True;` try `User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;`

Comment: It is a desktop forms application.As far as I can tell my client username has no access to the database.That is why I want to know if I should specify the admin password and user somewhere

Comment: @VDohnal Using server credentials  <add name="dbname" connectionString="Server=myservername;Database=dbname;User Id=domain\adminusername; Password=myadminpw;"/> I get the error  login failed for my  user domain\adminusername

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set up access to the database for the connecting user/client PC. You sort of "map" a user on the domain to a SQL user or group

Go to SQL management studio> connect to your database> expand databases > expand 'security' and then 'logins'

right click logins and select new login. search for the user of the connecting user/client PC. Then under the "user mapping" tab you can give access to the specific database. it may be best to give "db_owner" at first just to ensure you have the connection. after that, you should limit the access to only what is needed.

you can always check the SQL events log from the SQL machine itself and see what the specific authentication issues may be. go to  "Events" in the Administrative tools (which is in control panel) and you can see SQL specific events.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I kept the Integrated and added my user profile to the log in

Answer (score 0):

Either you can remove the `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string and insert the username and password of a Login you create in you SQL Server database to your connection string.

Or, you can create a login for the user under which your c# program is running (yourself - for testing, domain service account under production) to the SQL Server and give it appropriate read/write access.

More information on connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com

More information on how to create login in SQL Server : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you set `Integrated Security=True` ,   the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
Since you are trying from a different PC than the one that is running the SQL instance it is much likely the acount you are trying to connect with differs from the acount registered to the instance log in.
what you can do is:
Use `Integrated Security=sspi` and provide the login credentials, e.g:

```
connectionString="Server=remoteservername;Database=dbname;User id= myUser; Password=myPass;Integrated Security=sspi";
```

you can also set `Integrated Security=false` and also provide the credentials, (but the connection won't be using Windows Athentication)